# Is this the right way to define a function?

Tags: python

```
def main():
time = input("What time is it? ")
if convert(time) >= 7.0 and <= 8.0:
    print("breakfast time")
elif time >= 12.0 and time <= 13.0:
    print("lunch time")
elif time >= 18.0 and time <= 19.0:
    print("dinner time")

def convert(time):
   hours, min = time.split(":")
   nm = int(min) / 6
   return int(nm) + int(hours)
```

That's my code and what I'm trying to do is convert, let's say **7:30** to **7.5**.

Comment: No, it's wrong. The function body must be indented compared to the `def` line. (You did it correctly for the second function.)

Comment: You may need to return this in the end: **return int(nm) + ":" + int(hours)**

Comment: @LoukasPap, That will certainly produce an error of not being able to concatenate int and str. Their conversion of `nm` to int also does not make sense, nor their devision by 6

Comment: Yes, my bad. But if he wants to convert 7:30 to 7.5, then it will be 7 + 5 which will result in 12. I think. Maybe `nm+":"+hours`.

Comment: @LoukasPap, the problem is their division by 6 and conversion to int... They can perfectly do 7 + 0.5

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues in your Python code.

1. The `convert` function is defined inside the `main` function, which will cause a NameError because Python doesn't support nested function calls in the way your code is structured.
2. The line `if convert(time) >= 7.0 and <= 8.0:` has a syntax error because it doesn't specify what `<= 8.0` refers to. It should be `if convert(time) >= 7.0 and convert(time) <= 8.0:`
3. The conversion calculation in the `convert` function is incorrect. You are trying to convert the minutes to the decimal representation, but `int(min) / 6` is not correct. You need to divide the minutes by 60.

Fixed version.

```py
def main():
    time = input("What time is it? ")
    converted_time = convert(time)
    if converted_time >= 7.0 and converted_time <= 8.0:
        print("breakfast time")
    elif converted_time >= 12.0 and converted_time <= 13.0:
        print("lunch time")
    elif converted_time >= 18.0 and converted_time <= 19.0:
        print("dinner time")
    else:
        print("Not a meal time")

def convert(time):
   hours, min = map(int, time.split(":"))
   nm = min / 60
   return nm + hours
```